# New to Access, need assistance with function

Tags: database, ms-access-2003

In Access, I need to update prices from a table from 2 different columns.  Some are zero, but I need to pull the cell that has the price.  I'm trying to pull Price A or B into Base in my query.

Base: IIf([NEGITS]>0=[NEGITS][ITSMULT]>0=[ITSMULT])

I keep getting invalid syntax error. Can you please help me find the correct function to use?

Thank you so much!

Base: IIf([NEGITS]>0=[NEGITS][ITSMULT]>0=[ITSMULT]) - invalid snytax error

Expr1: IIf([NEGITS]>0=[NEGITS],[ITSMULT]>0=[ITSMULT]) Syntax error (comma)

Expr1: IIf([NEGITS]>0=[NEGITS][ITSMULT]>0=[ITSMULT])   invalid snytax error

Base: IIf([NEGITS]>0=NEGITS][ITSMULT>0=[ITSMULT]) invalid snytax error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Base: IIf([NEGITS]>0,[NEGITS],IIf([ITSMULT]>0,[ITSMULT],0))
```